# Migration of database from SQL Server to Azure SQL

Tags: sql, azure, database-migration

I want to migrate the database and servers which are very big (around 1TB). Which process should I use to migrate it?

Comment: I can tell you _not_ to use any process that involves bacpac as they are very inefficient for large databases

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a backup and upload it to an Azure Storage Account and restore the DB on Azure Sql Database from it or you can use Azure Database Migration Service:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/database-migration/